# Choose the good analyzer for French AND programmatic languages

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search, analyzer

I'm working on a search engine ( Java J2ee, Hibernate, Hibernate Search and Lucene ). I analyse documents content. All my system is OK, but one problem is persisting.
The choice of the analyzer !

My documents are in French, and it's important because the research are in French.
But my search engine should be able to search programming language names like ( Java, COBOL, C, C#, C++, .... )

I'm now using the French analyzer of Lucene, and the problem is the results of the requests for the terms "C", "C++", "C#".
I would like to have : ["C" or "C++" or "C#"] => "C" but I have => ""

I'm actually a newbie on these technologies and I would like to know which analyzer should I use OR if I have to implement a specific one.

(I'm Using hibernate search 3.0.0.GA (which is VERY old ... ) and I can't change the version).

Thanxs

Answer (score 0):

See `FrenchAnalyzer.FRENCH_STOP_WORDS`, "c" is a french stop word.  You can define your own stop set through the appropriate [`FrenchAnalyzer` constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/fr/FrenchAnalyzer.html#FrenchAnalyzer%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet%29).

You can start from the default set and just remove undesirable stop words, when defining your own.  The full default french stop set is:

```
"a", "afin", "ai", "ainsi", "après", "attendu", "au", "aujourd", "auquel", "aussi",
"autre", "autres", "aux", "auxquelles", "auxquels", "avait", "avant", "avec", "avoir",
"c", "car", "ce", "ceci", "cela", "celle", "celles", "celui", "cependant", "certain",
"certaine", "certaines", "certains", "ces", "cet", "cette", "ceux", "chez", "ci",
"combien", "comme", "comment", "concernant", "contre", "d", "dans", "de", "debout",
"dedans", "dehors", "delà", "depuis", "derrière", "des", "désormais", "desquelles",
"desquels", "dessous", "dessus", "devant", "devers", "devra", "divers", "diverse",
"diverses", "doit", "donc", "dont", "du", "duquel", "durant", "dès", "elle", "elles",
"en", "entre", "environ", "est", "et", "etc", "etre", "eu", "eux", "excepté", "hormis",
"hors", "hélas", "hui", "il", "ils", "j", "je", "jusqu", "jusque", "l", "la", "laquelle",
"le", "lequel", "les", "lesquelles", "lesquels", "leur", "leurs", "lorsque", "lui", "là",
"ma", "mais", "malgré", "me", "merci", "mes", "mien", "mienne", "miennes", "miens", "moi",
"moins", "mon", "moyennant", "même", "mêmes", "n", "ne", "ni", "non", "nos", "notre",
"nous", "néanmoins", "nôtre", "nôtres", "on", "ont", "ou", "outre", "où", "par", "parmi",
"partant", "pas", "passé", "pendant", "plein", "plus", "plusieurs", "pour", "pourquoi",
"proche", "près", "puisque", "qu", "quand", "que", "quel", "quelle", "quelles", "quels",
"qui", "quoi", "quoique", "revoici", "revoilà", "s", "sa", "sans", "sauf", "se", "selon",
"seront", "ses", "si", "sien", "sienne", "siennes", "siens", "sinon", "soi", "soit",
"son", "sont", "sous", "suivant", "sur", "ta", "te", "tes", "tien", "tienne", "tiennes",
"tiens", "toi", "ton", "tous", "tout", "toute", "toutes", "tu", "un", "une", "va", "vers",
"voici", "voilà", "vos", "votre", "vous", "vu", "vôtre", "vôtres", "y", "à", "ça", "ès",
"été", "être", "ô"
```

Answer (score 0):

I come back because I am not satisfied by my solution ( Doesn't work ... ).
I modified the StopWords list ( I suppressed the "c" word ) and I put ("C","C++","C#") in the stem exclusion list.
I modified the constructor to set the Stem exclusion list.

In my class to index's file i've got :

```
// I've verified my custom constructor was called
@Analyzer(impl = CustomFrenchAnalyzer.class)
...
```

I create a print of the query constructed with my custom analyzer and send to lucene, for the keyWords C, C++, C# the query is SContent:**c** (and not c, c++ or c# like i would )

If somebody know why ??

Here is my CustomFrenchAnalyzer class :

```
public class CustomFrenchAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

protected static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomFrenchAnalyzer.class);
/**
 * Extended list of custom French stopwords ( Without "c" ).
 */
public final static String[] FRENCH_STOP_WORDS = { "a", "afin", "ai", "ainsi", "après", "attendu", "au", "aujourd", "auquel", "aussi", "autre", "autres", "aux", "auxquelles", "auxquels", "avait",
        "avant", "avec", "avoir", "car", "ce", "ceci", "cela", "celle", "celles", "celui", "cependant", "certain", "certaine", "certaines", "certains", "ces", "cet", "cette", "ceux", "chez",
        "ci", "combien", "comme", "comment", "concernant", "contre", "d", "dans", "de", "debout", "dedans", "dehors", "delà", "depuis", "derrière", "des", "désormais", "desquelles", "desquels",
        "dessous", "dessus", "devant", "devers", "devra", "divers", "diverse", "diverses", "doit", "donc", "dont", "du", "duquel", "durant", "dès", "elle", "elles", "en", "entre", "environ",
        "est", "et", "etc", "etre", "eu", "eux", "excepté", "hormis", "hors", "hélas", "hui", "il", "ils", "j", "je", "jusqu", "jusque", "l", "la", "laquelle", "le", "lequel", "les",
        "lesquelles", "lesquels", "leur", "leurs", "lorsque", "lui", "là", "ma", "mais", "malgré", "me", "merci", "mes", "mien", "mienne", "miennes", "miens", "moi", "moins", "mon", "moyennant",
        "même", "mêmes", "n", "ne", "ni", "non", "nos", "notre", "nous", "néanmoins", "nôtre", "nôtres", "on", "ont", "ou", "outre", "où", "par", "parmi", "partant", "pas", "passé", "pendant",
        "plein", "plus", "plusieurs", "pour", "pourquoi", "proche", "près", "puisque", "qu", "quand", "que", "quel", "quelle", "quelles", "quels", "qui", "quoi", "quoique", "revoici", "revoilà",
        "s", "sa", "sans", "sauf", "se", "selon", "seront", "ses", "si", "sien", "sienne", "siennes", "siens", "sinon", "soi", "soit", "son", "sont", "sous", "suivant", "sur", "ta", "te", "tes",
        "tien", "tienne", "tiennes", "tiens", "toi", "ton", "tous", "tout", "toute", "toutes", "tu", "un", "une", "va", "vers", "voici", "voilà", "vos", "votre", "vous", "vu", "vôtre", "vôtres",
        "y", "à", "ça", "ès", "été", "être", "ô" };

/**
 * Contains the stopwords used with the StopFilter.
 */
private Set stoptable = new HashSet();
/**
 * Contains words that should be indexed but not stemmed.
 */
private Set excltable = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("C", "C++", "C#"));
private String[] exclListe = { "C", "C++", "C#" };

/**
 * Builds an analyzer with the default stop words ({@link #FRENCH_STOP_WORDS}).
 */
public CustomFrenchAnalyzer() {
    setStemExclusionTable(exclListe);
    stoptable = StopFilter.makeStopSet(FRENCH_STOP_WORDS);
}

/**
 * Builds an analyzer with the given stop words.
 */
public CustomFrenchAnalyzer(String[] stopwords) {
    stoptable = StopFilter.makeStopSet(stopwords);
}

/**
 * Builds an analyzer with the given stop words.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public CustomFrenchAnalyzer(File stopwords) throws IOException {
    stoptable = new HashSet(WordlistLoader.getWordSet(stopwords));
}

/**
 * Builds an exclusionlist from an array of Strings.
 */
public void setStemExclusionTable(String[] exclusionlist) {
    excltable = StopFilter.makeStopSet(exclusionlist);
}

/**
 * Builds an exclusionlist from the words contained in the given file.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
/*
 * public void setStemExclusionTable(File exclusionlist) throws IOException { excltable = new HashSet(WordlistLoader.getWordSet(exclusionlist)); }
 */

/**
 * Creates a TokenStream which tokenizes all the text in the provided Reader.
 * 
 * @return A TokenStream build from a StandardTokenizer filtered with StandardFilter, StopFilter, FrenchStemFilter and LowerCaseFilter
 */
public final TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {

    if (fieldName == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fieldName must not be null");
    if (reader == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("reader must not be null");

    TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
    result = new StandardFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(result, stoptable);
    result = new FrenchStemFilter(result, excltable);
    // Convert to lowercase after stemming!
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    return result;
}
}
```

Thanks